# jQuery create elements correct syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('<div>', {
  'class': 'inner',
  'html': $('<p>').text('Id: ' + toManage[i].id)
}).appendTo($element);
```

I'm creating the code above dynamically. I need to use this syntax to create two html tags instead of only one p tag. How can this be achieved?

As an example, this is what I am looking to achieve:

```
$('<div>', {
  'class': 'inner',
  'html': $('<p>').text('Id:'),
  $('<p>').text(toManage[i].id)
}).appendTo($element);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just append the paragraph elements to the div.

```js
var $element = $("body");

var myDiv = $('<div>', {
  'class': 'inner'
});

myDiv.append($('<p>').text('Id:1'))
myDiv.append($('<p>').text('Id:2'))

myDiv.appendTo($element);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It can also be done in one append

```js
var $element = $("body");

var myDiv = $('<div>', {
  'class': 'inner'
});

myDiv.append($('<p>').text('Id:1'), $('<p>').text('Id:2'));

myDiv.appendTo($element);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or with append in the element creation itself

```js
var $element = $("body");

var myDiv2 = $('<div>', {
  'class': 'inner',
  append: [$('<p>').text('Id:1'), $('<p>').text('Id:2')]
});

myDiv2.appendTo($element);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this

```js
$(document).on('click','#addCode',function(){
    $('#idwhereyouappendcode').append(
    $('<p/>')
        .attr("id", "newdiv1")
        .addClass("newdiv mynewclass")
        .text("hello world")
    );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="idwhereyouappendcode"></div>
<button id="addCode">ADD</button>
```